# Continuous EMR consistency failures when writing CSV data in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm using Spark to update some CSV metadata.

The structure is that I aggregate a bunch of data into a CSV file and write it into a directory.

#### Code

```
    val processedMetadataDf = spark.read.csv(readPath)
    val processCount = processedMetadataDf.count()
    
    // Updated entry to processed metadata records
    val appendedRow = Seq(s3filePath)
    val appendedRowDf = appendedRow.toDF()
    if (processCount == 0) {
        println("Generating New Processed Metadata Enty")
        appendedRowDf.write.option("compression","uncompressed").mode("overwrite").csv("s3://" + metadataPath + "/PROCESSED/" + "month-05")
    } else {
        println("Union Merge With Existing Data")
        val mergedFrame = processedMetadataDf.union(appendedRowDf).toDF
        mergedFrame.toDF.show()
        mergedFrame.write.option("compression","uncompressed").mode("overwrite").csv("s3://" + metadataPath + "/PROCESSED/" + "month-05")      
    }
  }
```

`month-05` in the above example is a directory and there should ideally just be 1 single CSV written into it from Spark. The first run of this works, the second run hits me with an inconsistency failure.

> com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.exception.ConsistencyException: 1 items inconsistent (no s3 object for associated metadata item).

I've ran EMRFS Sync, but my real question is *why* is this happening? I'm not modifying these files at all outside this script shown above.

My high-level logic is:

1. If first time writing, write dataframe to CSV in s3 path
2. If previous data existed, union the data, then write CSV to s3 path

Both are using overwrite as shown.